# How to match Event ID, Knowledge Base DB with winlogbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am new to Winlogbeat and would like to know how to match Event ID, Knowledge Base DB (https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/default.aspx) with winlogbeat

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to build a table and then use the translate filter in LS - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-translate.html1